# Creating custom Editor Object for ArcMap and tie it to custom tool?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects

I have some spatial enabled tables tables in SQL Server 2008 and add them to ArcMap using custom layers(or a a spatial enabled OLE DB provider) successfully,but as you know,the editor toolbar of ArcMap doen't get enabled for these layers.
Is it possible (and if yes how) to create a custom "Editor Object" for ArcMap which implements all necessary interfaces(like IEditor,IEditor2,ISnapEnvironment,...) and use this custom editor for these custom layers?and is it possible to create a "Sketch Tool" which can work with this custom editor and have same properties like snapping?

Answer (score 1):

These links may be of some help, though what you want to do may require a lot of work.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000003v4000000

EDIT: Well, I wanted to post more links but the anti spam tool on this site won't let me post more than one hyperlink until I earn rep here.

Comment: Thank you for this link,but it's about custom layers,and as you know ESRI has mentioned explicity that "Custom Layers" and "Plug in Data source" are read-only.There is no any guide line in this link how to implement a tool to (for exam)create feature on map interactively.I need to implement a tool using ArcObject(by implementing ICommand,ITool and ISketchTool)that enables users to create a feature on the map,and have snap capability.(The tool without this capability is quite simple using IRubberband).Any tool with I implement,can use "ESRI Editor Object",but not usful for me.

Comment: There are custom editors out there, like the OpenStreetMap Editor for ArcMap. This seems to work by handling the conversions of the data from a custom layer to an ArcGIS specific Feature Class and then the edits can be done, once finished outputting straight back to the custom layer format. I would be happy to be wrong on this.